# Is it possible to add a parameter or something else to set timeout time of a query when we are running query through pgAdmin/psql client?

Tags: psql, pgadmin

I want to run a query on a remote database with a timeout option.

For example :

```
Select * from XYZ table
```

if this query does not return any result within 2 min then automatically stop this query process.

dummy psql

`@timeout select * from XYZ`

is it possible to pass timeout parameter at run time without touching any conf file?

Answer (score 0):

In psql use `statement_timeout(n)` where `n` is in milliseconds. Or you can set `statement_timeout` in postgresql.conf but it will affect all sessions.

Comment: set statement_timeout = xxx ms 
is used for setting the timeout for all query run after this  query .
But in this case, we need to set timeout first before run query and reset after the query.
I want timeout automatically set or reset before and after run any query.

Comment: Can you use `statement_timeout(n)` before the query, run the query and then set it back?

Comment: I try like below :

1. set statement_timeout=10000;
2. Select * from XYZ table;
3.set statement_timeout=0; /default timeout

it is working fine but in this case ,we need to do extra work (set and reset timeout)

Comment: I try this also :
1. statement_timeout (10000)  select * from XYZ;    
2. set statement_timeout (10000)  select * from XYZ; 
both cases not working.

Comment: When you write `set statement_timeout=10000` you mean you did in the postgresql.conf file?

Comment: No, I have run set statement_timeout=10000; query from pgAdmin;

Comment: And it didn't help you? Have you tried to run those commands in psql directly?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to run commands  according to your suggestions but it not works.

Comment: Try to use `set statement_timeout to 10000`. Then run `show statement_timeout `. It should show you 10s.